# Positioning HTML-elements, make the utmost ancestor behave block-element-style

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

In my HTML5/javascript application, I am drawing a analog clock on a multi layer canvas (the reason for multi layer is optimization due to javascript rendered animations). Below the clock I would like to show time with digits. This is what would like to achieve:

[image]

This is what I have achieved

[image]

And here's the markup for it:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="analog">
        <canvas id="canvBackground"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvDigitsHours"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvDigitsMinutes"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvHandsMinutes"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvHandsHours"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="digital">
        16:30
    </div>
</div>



#container {
}
#analog {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
#analog > canvas {
    position: absolute;
}
#digital {
    display: block;
}
```

How can I make my parent element, `<div id="analog">`, behave block-element-style when it has children with position: absolute?

Edit 1: Trying @CBroe's proposal (if I din't missunderstood you?). Using `padding -top: 250px;` both the `#analog` an `#digital` moved 250px down:
[image]

Comment: You can't, absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the normal layout flow. But since I assume you know the height of your canvasses (either absolute in terms of pixels, or at least in terms of aspect ratio), you can simply give the container element an according padding-top.

Comment: Thnx @CBroe but that did not produce the desired result. :-(

Comment: Then create a [mcve] please, so that we can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify `relative` positions for both child elements to get this to display correctly.

Hope this helps!

```css
#container {
  margin: 40px;
}

#canvCenterExample {
  background: red;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#canvBackground {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #BFB4FD;
}

#analog {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#analog>canvas {
  position: absolute;
}

#digital {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="analog">
    <canvas id="canvBackground"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvCenterExample"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="digital">16:30</div>
</div>
```